# Unable to get div value for voting system

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When I click on `#upvote` the `#vote` increases by 1 and when `#downvote` is clicked it decreases by 1.  But when the vote value is "-1" and if the upvote is clicked the vote value becomes "1" and not "0".

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){

    $('#upvote').click(function() {
        var VoteValue = $('#vote').val();
        $('#vote').text(VoteValue+1);

    });

$('#downvote').click(function() {
        var VoteValue1 = $('#vote').val();
        $('#vote').text(VoteValue1-1);

    });

});
</script>


<div id="upvote" style="font-size:22px;">+</div>
<div id="vote" style="font-size:22px;">0</div>
<div id="downvote" style="font-size:22px;">-</div>
```

Any idea to what might be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [**parseInt()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    $('#upvote').click(function() {
        var VoteValue = $('#vote').text();
        $('#vote').text(parseInt(VoteValue)+1);

    });

$('#downvote').click(function() {
        var VoteValue1 = $('#vote').text();
        $('#vote').text(parseInt(VoteValue1)-1);

    });

});
```

## [Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c2hza859/)

**Note:** `.text()` should use for getting value of DIV instead of `val()`

Answer (score 2):

First, you should use html() or text() instead of val(), val() is for inputs or textarea.

Then, you should use parseInt, to make sure you manipulate the right types : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

If that doesn't solve it, then create a jsfiddle so that we can reproduce the problem.

Last, beware of duplicate ids if you have multiple voting systems on the same page.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.text()` instead of `.val()`, and use `+` to parse the string into a numeric.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){

    $('#upvote').click(function() {
        var VoteValue = +$('#vote').text();
        $('#vote').text(VoteValue+1);

    });

    $('#downvote').click(function() {
        var VoteValue1 = +$('#vote').text();
        $('#vote').text(VoteValue1-1);

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="upvote" style="font-size:22px;">+</div>
<div id="vote" style="font-size:22px;">0</div>
<div id="downvote" style="font-size:22px;">-</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Tushar490/m5zok1n4/):**

Firstly, `$('#vote').val()` should be `$('#vote').text()` . Now these values will be of `string` type. **Parse them to int** first to work them correct . Because then it would only append the digits rather incrementing or decrementing .

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#upvote').click(function () {
    var VoteValue = parseInt($('#vote').text());
    $('#vote').text(VoteValue + 1);

  });

  $('#downvote').click(function () {
    var VoteValue1 = parseInt($('#vote').text());
    $('#vote').text(VoteValue1 - 1);

   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In an HTML document, .html() can be used to get the contents of any element. .val() used for input box.  http://api.jquery.com/html/

```
var VoteValue1 = $('#vote').html();
OR
var VoteValue1 = $('#vote').text();
```

Comment: first parse the value to int and then add or substract i.e. var VoteValue = parseInt($('#vote').val());